# Writing a byte array as a file to a web location

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest

```
 private void CreateFile(byte[] outByteArray)
        {
            //Create a new file containing the returned PDF document 
            string filename = "C:\\myfile.pdf";
            FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs2);
            w.Write(outByteArray);
            w.Close();
            fs2.Close();
        }
```

This is my current code.
I am writing to the server's drive. It is working fine.

But now I have to write the byte array to a web folder

I mean to some folder like http://tyyet.com/rsfgqs/destination/
and save it there in the name myfile.pdf.

How can I do that?
Can I use HttpWebRequest for that?

Comment: Is there a problem with writing the folder locally as you are currently, and then moving the file? That'd probably involve changing less code.

Comment: You need to send a request to some code on that server that is willing and able to write a file for you.